# Using process to get data from C++ program to Python program

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to continuously send a string from a C++ program to a Python program using subprocess.

The C++ program runs continuously.

Here's my C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
std::printf("This Sucks");
}
```

And here's my Python Program:

```
import os
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
process = Popen('./Subprocess', stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines = True, shell = True, preexec_fn = os.setsid)
while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == '' and process.poll is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(output)
```

In the form shown above, the Python program will read in and print "This Sucks" one time. However, if I put the print statement in the C++ program in a loop so that it prints repeatedly, the Python program hangs and prints nothing.

I need the print statement in the C++ program to run continously in a while loop, and the Python program has to be able to read from the C++ program as it runs indefinitely and continously print "This Sucks" over and over again.

The end goal is to have the C++ program continously printing out sensor data and the Python program capable of reading it in.

What do I need to change to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python program is expecting to read a single line at a time. Each line is terminated by a newline character.

Your C++ program prints the same string endlessly, but without a trailing newline character. So, to the Python program this looks like an unending line, so it just keeps reading, and reading it, until it runs out of memory.

Simply add a newline character, "`\n`" at the end of the string.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Follow up question. If I were doing something in the C++ file to where I had to run the C++ program with sudo, what would I change in the Python script to run the C++ program as sudo?